# Iframe loading/buffering issue

Tags: apache, iframe, proxy, load-balancing

I am currently having some issues that I believe to be related to an iframe.

My website homepage has a video on, with a simple "play" button that when pressed will load on iframe with a url from my root, video.html with a embedded to play.

My site is load-balanced, I had no issues with apache 2.2 but now i am using apache 2.4.

The video and frame loaded instantly with 2.2, but in 2.4 I click the button - the audio for the video starts playing, but the tab is loading something and soon after the video appears.

I can close the video and reopen and it does the same thing. In all browsers

I can visit the referenced URL in the iframe to pull the video from via the balancer and it plays right away.

Anyone know what sort of configuration element i may be missing? :)

Comment: You should show the code that displays the image or perhaps parts of the Apache config related to you question. It might help get an answer.

Comment: My deflate options are pretty standard and the iframe call is a simple iframe calling another page on the domaim, video.html